# I am not able to read dat file from S3 bucket using lambda function

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have been trying to read dat file from one s3 bucket and convert it into CSV and then compress it and put it into another bucket
for open and reading i am using below code but it is throwing me an error No such file or directory

`with open(f's3://{my_bucket}/{filenames}', 'rb') as dat_file:
         print(dat_file)`'''

Answer (score 0):

The Python language does not natively know how to access Amazon S3.

Instead, you can use the `boto3` AWS SDK for Python. See: [S3 — Boto 3 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html)

You also have two choices about how to access the content of the file:

- Download the file to your local disk using `download_file()`, then use `open()` to access the local file, *or*
- Use `get_object()` to obtain a `StreamingBody` of the file contents

See also: [Amazon S3 Examples — Boto 3 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-examples.html)